# Multiple certificates(signing and encryption) for Identitiy Provider

Tags: saml, onelogin, ruby-saml

I want to create a metadata with multiple Service Providers certificates(*signing* and *encryption*) for **OneLogin SAML**. But I don't know what settings parameters have to be set for that.

I am using **ruby-saml** gem. And my current settings is as follows

```
signing_pem = File.read 'signing.pem'
encryption_pem = File.read 'encryption.pem'

settings = OneLogin::RubySaml::Settings.new
settings.single_logout_service_url = "https://sp.com/slo"
settings.assertion_consumer_service_url = "https://sp.com/callback"
settings.issuer = "myissuer"
settings.idp_sso_target_url = 'https://idp.com/redirect/sso'
settings.idp_slo_target_url = 'https://idp.com/redirect/sls'
settings.idp_cert_multi = { signing: [signing_pem], encryption: [encryption_pem] }
settings.security[:authn_requests_signed]   = true
settings.security[:logout_requests_signed]  = true
settings.security[:logout_responses_signed] = true
settings.security[:want_assertions_signed]  = true
settings.security[:metadata_signed]         = true
settings.security[:want_assertions_encrypted] = true
```

Following code is used to generate metadata

`OneLogin::RubySaml::Metadata.new.generate settings`

I am getting Metadata without any certificates

```
"<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><md:EntityDescriptor 
ID='_eda16671-6d18-4273-b295-3cdd94f9886c' entityID='myissuer' 
xmlns:md='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:metadata'><md:SPSSODescriptor 
AuthnRequestsSigned='true' WantAssertionsSigned='true' 
protocolSupportEnumeration='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:protocol'> 
<md:SingleLogoutService 
Binding='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-Redirect' 
Location='https://sp.com/auth/slo' 
ResponseLocation='https://sp.com/auth/slo'/> 
<md:AssertionConsumerService 
Binding='urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:bindings:HTTP-POST' 
Location='https://sp.com/auth/callback' index='0' isDefault='true'/> 
</md:SPSSODescriptor></md:EntityDescriptor>"
```

[Also, I have tried to create metadata directly from SAMLTool website. And there is no option available to enter different certificates for *signing* and *encryption*](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WciXY.png)

Answer (score 2):

Service provider settings attributes are:

`settings.certificate = "public cert"` # used for encripting SAML response

`settings.private_key = "private cert"` # used for decripting SAML response

`settings.certificate_new = "public cert"` # used for certificate rollover, appears as secondary certificate in metadata file so that Idp systems could pick it up

I don't think there is a feature for multiple SP certificates, at least I'm not aware of it

Comment: Yes, these statements are correct but to go further when the settings.certificate is used in conjunction with "want_assertions_encrypted] = true" the SP certificate appears twice in the metadata. One labelled signing and the other labelled encryption. In the original example the certificates are imported as IDP certificates and so do not display in the SP metadata. Ruby Saml does not support separate encryption and signing SP certificates as in the majority of cases these are the same.